# how to deal with more than 10 decimal point INT in C language?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, struct, types

i have this `Members.txt`with this content:

```
3
Rebaz salimi 3840221821 09188888888
4
95120486525
95120482642
95120541325
95120860452
```

i m reading it into array objects from `struct books`and`struct MEMBERS`and print out to the screen.here is my codes:

```
struct books
{
   long long int id;
   char stname[20];
   char name[20];
   char Author[20];
   int quantity;
   float Price;
   int count[100];
   int code[100];
   int rackno;
   char *cat;
   struct meroDate issued;
   struct meroDate duedate;
 };
 struct MEMBERS
 {
   long long int code;
   char Fname[40];
   char Lname[40];
   long long int Pnum;
   float bedeh;
   float credit;
   struct meroDate issued;
   struct meroDate duedate;
  };

 struct MEMBERS cur_member[100];
 struct books cur_book[100];

 int main()
{

    getdataMEMBERS();

   return 0;
   }

   int getdataMEMBERS()
  {
        FILE *myfile = fopen("Members.txt", "r");
        FILE *myfile1 = fopen("Members.txt", "r");
    if (myfile == NULL) {
                   printf("Cannot open file.\n");
         return 1;
                        }
                     else {
                            char ch;
                           int count = 0;
      do
        {
            ch = fgetc(myfile);
              if (ch == '\n') count++;
          } while (ch != EOF);
             rewind(myfile);

         //Since you put 2 earlier in the member.txt we need to dump it
         //so that it wont affect the scanning process
      int temp;
       fscanf(myfile, "%d", &temp);
      printf("%d\n", temp);
         //Now scan all the line inside the text
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        fscanf(myfile, "%s %s %lld %lld\n %d", cur_member[i].Fname, 
        cur_member[i].Lname, &cur_member[i].code, &cur_member[i].Pnum 
        ,&cur_book[i].quantity);

                printf("%s %s %lld %lld\n 
         %d\n",cur_member[i].Fname,cur_member[i].Lname,
       cur_member[i].code,cur_member[i].Pnum , cur_book[i].quantity);

        int j;
        for(j=0;j<cur_book[i].quantity;j++)
        {
            fscanf(myfile,"%d\n",&cur_book[j].id);
            printf("%d\n",cur_book[j].id);
        }


       }

   }
         fclose(myfile);

}
```

once i `printf`this code:

```
int j;
 for(j=0;j<cur_book[i].quantity;j++)
 {
  fscanf(myfile,"%d\n",&cur_book[j].id);
  printf("%d\n",cur_book[j].id);
 }
```

it gives me:

```
  631206013
  631202130
  631260813
  631579940
```

which should suppose to give me:

```
  95120486525
  95120482642
  95120541325
  95120860452
```

i had changed the data type to `long long double id;`in `struct books`but still gaves me this three output:

```
  631206013
  631202130
  631260813
  631579940
```

would anyone knows where is the problem might be? datatype or something else?

Comment: Is there any need to do calculations with these numbers? If not, just store *strings*. `double` doesn't make *any* sense with integer numbers, you will only lose precision. Try `long long` for a wider `int`.

Comment: Why `long long double` (which doesn't exist as a type, do you mean `long double`?) instead of `long long int` which is at least 64 bits on supported systems?

Comment: You are printing (and scanning) a `long long int` with the `%d` conversion specifier?

Comment: As for your problem, after you changed the type to `long long int` (which I suppose you *really* mean) did you remember to change the `printf` format when printing the value? *Everywhere?*

Comment: @FelixPalmen there is no string type in C,do u mean array of char?

Comment: @moh89: Because there's no string type, programmers often use "string" to mean a NUL-terminated (const) char[] array. There's no ambiguity in that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i had used long long double and doesnt gave me any error! so means it might be exist?!

Comment: @moh89 there's no string **type**, but a clear description what a *string* **is** in the C standard. Should be clear enough.

Comment: @DavidBowling yep! do u have any other idea?

Comment: @moh89 Again, there is no such type as `long long double`. There is `long double` and `long long int`. The type `long long int` can be shortened to `long long`.

Comment: @moh89 ("*You are printing (and scanning) a long long int with the %d conversion specifier?*") if you answer *yes* here, you're doing it *wrong*. `long long` needs the `%lld` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong *format specifier* for a `long long` in your `printf` call so the behaviour of your code is actually undefined.

Use `%lld` to output the `id` member.

Really though if you're using a number as an *identifier* rather than something on which numerical calculations are being performed, then it would be more natural to use a `char[]` type. That will allow you to preserve leading zeros &c.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compiler supporting C99, you can hope it implements `uint64_t` in `<stdint.h>`, that will give you enough integer precision to handle over 18 decimal digits.

You're going to have to modify the code of course, you can't use `%d` to scan a `uint64_t`; you must use `"%" SCNu64` and then `"%" PRIu64` to print it. Yes, those are correctly written, it's two adjacent string literals which will be compiled into a single string.

But if these things are just identifiers, you might just treat them as strings.

Comment: i tried it and gaves me same result! then ,it doesnt worked!